# Google Sheets return multiple columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for use in Google Sheets where it returns an array of arrays for the purpose of filling out multiple columns and rows.
I've got

```
var results = new Array(2);
var info = new Array(2);
info[0] = "some string";
info[1] = "other string";
results[0] = info;
results[1] = info;
return results;
```

The first column will be blank when it should have "some string", while the second contains "other string"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are asking about Custom Functions in Google Spreadsheets, your code currently returns a 2x2 table with the values:

```
|----------------------------|
| some string | other string |
| some string | other string |
|----------------------------|
```

If you want the following:

```
|----------------------------|
| some string | other string |
|----------------------------|
```

Then your code should be:

```
var results = new Array(2);
var info = new Array(2);
info[0] = "some string";
info[1] = "other string";
results[0] = info;
return results;
```

Comment: Simply put: A Google Sheets custom function returns an Array of rows, each element of which is an Array of cell values. If it returns a scalar instead that's a single cell's value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = new Array(2);
var info = new Array(2);
info[0] = "some string";
info[1] = "other string";
results[0] = info;
return results;
```

I tried your code on multiple rows containing data but got error that Google Sheet can't write as it will overwrite next line.

I made changes to first line then it worked

```
var results = new Array(1);
var info = new Array(2);
info[0] = "some string";
info[1] = "other string";
results[0] = info;
return results;
```

Thank You.
[Snapshot of code used in actual project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v96z8.png)